# password_verify принцип работы

Tags: php, password-hash

Файл регистрации, шифрования пароля:

```
 $finite_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (name, surname, login, 
password, mail, bornDD, bornMM, bornYY, sex) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', 
'$login', '$finite_password', '$mail', '$bornDD', '$bornMM', '$bornYY', ' 
$sex')");
if ($result2 === FALSE) {
    echo "Ошибка записи в базу: ".mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Файл авторизации:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (empty($myrow['password'])) {
exit ("Извините, введённый вами login или пароль неверный.");
}

else {
    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT password FROM users WHERE login = '$login' LIMIT 1 ");
    $finite_password = $query->fetch_assoc()['password'];

    if ( password_verify($password, $finite_password) ) { 
    $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['login']; 
    $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id']; ?>
    <div class="centerr">
        <div class="helpcenterr">
            <br>
        <?
            echo "Вы успешно вошли на сайт, как ".$_SESSION['login']."!"."&nbsp"."<a style='color:#8600D3; font-family:Arial;'; href='index.php'><br>  Главная страница</a>";
        echo "Вы зашли";
            }
            else {
            exit ("Извините, введённый вами login или пароль неверный.");
            }
            }
```

Пишет ошибку: **Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in W:\domains\work\reg\enter.php on line 87** 87 строка: $finite_password = $query->fetch_assoc()['password'];
Не понимаю, что не так. Помогите разобраться или расскажите, где я не так что понял по проверке пароля через password_verify;
Я новичок в этом всем, если не сложно опишите процесс, где я ошибся.

Comment: использовать `mysql` расширение не рекомендуется. Переходите на `PDO`. У `$query` нет метода `fetch_assoc()` и быть не может. Также не стоит забывать, что запрос может вернуть 0 строк. Поэтому `['password']` - может быть бессмысленно.

Comment: @ArchDemon мне сделать fetch_assoc() через PDO?

Comment: Почитать документацию на PDO или статью на хабре или любом другом ресурсе